# Capture card not working after updating to Windows 10 April 2018

Tags: windows-10, video-capture, windows-10-v1803

After updating to Windows 10 April 2018 (1803) my video capture card (Razer Ripsaw) isn’t being recognized by applications. It shows up properly in Device Manager and I have reinstalled the drivers but nothing seems to help. It just doesn’t show up working when trying to capture video.

Answer (score 1):

The new update changed privacy settings and by default seems to not allow access. You need to go to Settings, Privacy, Camera and allow access to camera. A capture card is considered to be a camera and when access is allowed applications can once again use the card.